# Who are all the superheroes on the Hellcat #2 cover?

Tags: marvel

I have seen this image on [CBR](http://www.comicbookresources.com/article/leth-williams-get-their-claws-into-patsy-walker-aka-hellcat):
[image: Patsy Walker AKA Hellcat issue #2 cover]

Who are all the women on the picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valkyrie, Captain Marvel, Captain Marvel, Ms. Marvel, Squirrel Girl, She-Hulk, Miss Marvel and Patsy Walker (AKA Hellcat)
[image]

Comment: That is not Thor, but Valkyrie/Brunhilde. There are nine characters on the picture, and I count six names in your answer.

Comment: That's 6 characters. There's 9 people in the image.

Comment: (Ten characters if one counts Tippy-Toe)

Comment: Who are the two on the left. I'm drawing a total blank

Comment: @Richard: They are Hawkeye (Kate Bishop) and America Chavez

Comment: Am I the only one who's concerned about the health implications of having vermin on the tabel

Comment: @Richard: She's not vermin, she's a **sentient little lady**.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

1. Carol Danvers - Captain Marvel (former Ms. Marvel, Binary)
2. Kamala Khan - Ms. Marvel
3. Patsy Walker - Hellcat
4. Jennifer Walters - She-Hulk
5. probably America Chavez - Miss America<sup>1</sup>
6. Kate Bishop - Hawkeye (among others)
7. Doreen Green - Squirrel Girl (pointing at Tippy Toe)
8. Tarene - Thor Girl <sup>2</sup>
9. Monica Rambeau - Spectrum (former Captain Marvel, Photon, others)

NOTES:

<sup>1</sup> Miss America is the only character I can find that matches the outfit, since her face is largely obscured.

<sup>2</sup> #8 might also be Brunnhilde - Valkyrie, but IMO the outfit more strongly resembles Thor Girl's uniform.

Comment: It seems to be far more likely to be Valkyrie. She and Hellcat were teammates (and roommates) in an [older serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie_(Marvel_Comics))

Comment: except every issue I've see her show up in, plus all the images I can find on Google, she has the same black outfit on. Tarene's outfit is a near-copy of Thor's blue/red one.

Comment: also, I don't think most of those people were teammates of Hellcat; she works for She-Hulk now but otherwise I don't remember her in the Avengers with any of the Marvel women, for example.

Comment: Tarene's outfit seems to always feature a cape, and her hair is not braided. (Conversely, Brunnhilde never has a cape, and her hair is always braided) The pictured woman's neck and arm metal protections match Brunnhilde's recent outfits. The red in Tarene's outfit comes nearly exclusively from her cape, but the pictured woman does not have one. So it is my feeling that the woman's outfit in the picture looks more like Brunnhilde's than Tarene's.